# How to find sources of RPI files *.elf and *.dat?

Tags: raspberry-pi, bootloader

We are working on a linux distribution that should work also on RPIs.
Instead of adding RPI repos/lists and install packages, we chose to download directly the boot files (bootcode.bin, *.dat and *.elf; everything else related to boot being built by ourselves - kernels, device trees, overlays, config.txt, cmdline.txt etc)

From the license point of view, we need to collect all the sources an provide them on request, but the problem is that we cannot find sources for downloaded boot files (bootcode.bin, *.dat and *.elf).

So, we download the package from here: http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/pool/main/r/raspberrypi-firmware/ install it and then deleted it. There is also this [ReadMe](https://stackoverflow.com), which correlates git tags with kernel builds, that we use to know exactly what version to download for different kernel versions.

Thank you for any help on this.